# How to suppress specific warnings in mysql error log when ignoring a table to replicate

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, error-log

Is there a way to make the mysql error log less chatty with certain warnings? I just threw in the *replicate-ignore-table* option in my.cnf so our health check table doesn't get replicated. However now I'm getting a couple warnings every minute telling me something that I specifically want to happen... and it's annoying, not to mention that the log will grow at a much faster rate now.

I thought adding *slave-skip-errors=1237* would fix it, but it's not an actual error that's stopping replication.

Any ideas?

```
2015-07-16 21:51:02 31210 [Warning] Error log throttle: 4 time(s) Error_code: 1237 "Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules" got suppressed.
2015-07-16 21:51:02 31210 [Warning] Slave SQL: Could not execute Query event. Detailed error: Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules; Error log throttle is enabled. This error will not be displayed for next 60 secs. It will be suppressed, Error_code: 1237
2015-07-16 21:53:01 31210 [Warning] Error log throttle: 3 time(s) Error_code: 1237 "Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules" got suppressed.
2015-07-16 21:53:01 31210 [Warning] Slave SQL: Could not execute Query event. Detailed error: Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules; Error log throttle is enabled. This error will not be displayed for next 60 secs. It will be suppressed, Error_code: 1237
2015-07-16 21:54:01 31210 [Warning] Error log throttle: 2 time(s) Error_code: 1237 "Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules" got suppressed.
2015-07-16 21:54:01 31210 [Warning] Slave SQL: Could not execute Query event. Detailed error: Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules; Error log throttle is enabled. This error will not be displayed for next 60 secs. It will be suppressed, Error_code: 1237
2015-07-16 21:55:01 31210 [Warning] Error log throttle: 3 time(s) Error_code: 1237 "Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules" got suppressed.
2015-07-16 21:55:01 31210 [Warning] Slave SQL: Could not execute Query event. Detailed error: Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules; Error log throttle is enabled. This error will not be displayed for next 60 secs. It will be suppressed, Error_code: 1237
2015-07-16 21:56:02 31210 [Warning] Error log throttle: 2 time(s) Error_code: 1237 "Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules" got suppressed.
2015-07-16 21:56:02 31210 [Warning] Slave SQL: Could not execute Query event. Detailed error: Slave SQL thread ignored the query because of replicate-*-table rules; Error log throttle is enabled. This error will not be displayed for next 60 secs. It will be suppressed, Error_code: 1237
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late, but since mysql v 8.0.13 there is a new parameter:
`log_error_suppression_list`:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_suppression_list

You could use `SET @@GLOBAL.log_error_suppression_list = "1237";` ... a comma separated list of error codes to suppress when writing to the error-log.

This variable was newly introduced and works in combination with the more general `log_warnings` which is mentioned above and also works for older mysql servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
Set global log_warnings=0;
```

Comment: This will stop the warnings to the err log hence the answer . What user asked but that will affect other warnings too... hence wanted if user us OK to use it.

Comment: You should add some flesh to your answer - like what you've stated in your comment.

Comment: Kind of, yes. But I don't want to globally turn off logging. I just want to suppress that one warning so it doesn't continually spam the error log.

Comment: Did you see this bug report or rather a feature request? --> https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73292

Comment: I doubt you have any other option than that... as such you might want to get fency by letting the health_check table replicate and making it blackhole... should that be ok for you?

Comment: Good suggestion on using the blackhole engine... I think i might try that out.

Comment: Actually, we need to see when the health check last wrote to the table.... so blackhole is out unfortunately.